# So, is WooCommerce on-topic now? I'm confused

Tags: discussion

After being told that categorically third-party plugins are off-topic I'm seeing a lot of WooCommerce questions getting bumped back to the front page by "community". Either the masters are no longer watching or WooCommerce is on topic now despite protests otherwise.

I officially I have no what is on-topic here.

Is WooCommerce on-topic or isn't it?

(You can begin downvoting me now).

Comment: It's still off-topic, just not gathering enough close votes.

Comment: Which suggests either the bulk of the community disagrees or it is too hard to earn enough rep to vote and too few users are available to vote. Perhaps if more votes were cast on answers... But that's none of my business.

Comment: "Community" is an autobot that bumps old questions that don't have answers with at least 1 upvote. If they're off topic then they've slipped through the community radar or haven't reached the close threshold. This is another inquiry that is less of a meta discussion and more of a community question that may be better asked and answered in [The Loop open chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The TLDR: WooCommerce questions are offtopic, and has always been offtopic. If you see a WooCommerce question, vote to close it. WooCommerce is offtopic**

Part of the maintenance of the site is more akin to gardening. None of us get paid and we can't triage questions for wether they fit on topic or need editing in realtime.

We also have a long history of questions, so what happened 5 or 6 years ago might not have gotten much notice back then, but get bumped up by the system on to the homepage. Similarly there are some very popular old questions that ask for recommendations, with lots of upvotes and answers that pose a quandry when they resurface.

Think of it as weeding the garden. You want to close the offtopic questions, edit and downvote/improve the poor ones, and upvote the good ones, and improve any answers similarly. If you garden well, and the answer rate is high enough, your stack thrives

> After being told that categorically third-party plugins are off-topic I'm seeing a lot of WooCommerce questions getting bumped back to the front page by "community".

A great opportunity to close vote! The community user is just Stack Exchanges automation, it doesn't know if a question is on or off topic, not unless it gets closed

> Either the masters are no longer watching or WooCommerce is on topic now despite protests otherwise.

It's still offtopic, it's a 3rd party plugin, it's time to start voting to close

Since these are being bumped, you'll notice these are older questions that might have escaped the oversight of users able to vote to close or leave feedback. Think of it as Stack Exchange percolating deep water back up to the surface for attention so it doesn't get stale, inevitably something it dredges up will be offtopic.

It doesn't help that lots of people want WooCommerce help but there's not much of it going around, deep WooCommerce knowledge is not so common. As a result WC questions don't get many answers, but they do get asked a lot. It's one of the main reasons the attempt at a dedicated WC stack failed, lots of questions, very few people able to answer things outside of basic theming questions

---

Some other notes

**Not all questions are ran through a filter**, things get missed. It could be that before a high rep user gets a chance to see a question, it gets answered and marked as correct and fades into the background. Perhaps the stack was especially busy that day, who knows. There is no perfect filter, nobody here gets paid, so there will be examples of open WooCommerce questions. That doesn't mean they're on topic. **Vote to close them**.

**As for the tag**, I believe multiple attempts were made to delete it and others, but they kept getting recreated by users. So yes, we did delete it, multiple times! But anybody past a certain amount of reputation can recreate it.

There's also the problem that sometimes it's useful to tag WooCommerce, e.g. it may be related to the question ( just because it's not a WooCommerce question doesn't mean it isn't involved ). For example, someone might want to work with a hook in WooCommerce, but has never used WP hooks before and needs to know how `add_action` works

**The TLDR: WooCommerce questions are offtopic, and have always been offtopic. If you see a WooCommerce question, vote to close it. WooCommerce is offtopic**

Comment: Sir, If woocommerce questions are not allowed then woocommerce tag should be officially removed. Else people will keep on posting and then downvoted and eventually feel low.

Comment: A few tags got deleted multiple times for that exact reason, and were promptly recreated by users. There are also people who tag perfectly valid questions as WooCommerce because it's contextual. E.g. someone who wants to hook into a WC hook, but doesn't understand how hooks work and is asking for an explanation, they might tag the question WooCommerce

Comment: wordpress.stackexchange.com should change name to wordpresscore.stackexchange.com

Comment: @forsvunnet but then where would we ask the WP CLI/Hello Dolly/Gutenberg/creating your own plugins/2FA/WP importer/etc questions? The rules simple, if you went to a 3rd party to get your wares, you should go to the 3rd party for support. You wouldn't go to the people who built your house for help with the TV you just bought because TVs go in houses right?

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges. It's more like the carpenter installed the type wrong of front door. One that opens inwards instead of outdoors. You complain to the carpenter, but the carpenter tells you to go and complain to the door manufacturer instead. You just wanted a house but have to go chase down 100s of third parties because you can't ask the carpenter for help.

Comment: You have a door warranty, you go to the door manufacturer, or the person who sold you the door. Stack Exchange is neither the seller or the manufacturer, or even the carpenter. 3rd party plugins are offtopic, the best place to go for ACF support is ACF support, the best place for WooCommerce support is WooCommerce support. This Q isn't a way you can argue that this isn't the case, it's just asking if WooCommerce has become on topic somehow, it hasn't. If you want to change official policy you should open a new Q

Comment: The best place for technical/code questions regarding WooCommerce or ACF (or any WordPress plugin) is https://stackoverflow.com/
I don't want to change the policy, it's too late. Wordpress stackexchange has long ago scared away professional developers from contributing to the community. My original comment simply pointed out the fact that this exchange is so strictly regulated that it might as well be renamed to better reflect what the exchange is actually used for and what kind of questions are allowed. Wordpress core only.

Comment: The best place for support is always the vendors support. Stack Overflow has a very wide open vague scope on purpose. We have a scope and we stick to it. I'd suggest focusing on constructive processes